# Is it possible to get a deadlock with ConcurrentHashMap with two threads lockRoot

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

if two threads put vals into one tree at same time

```
private final void contendedLock() {
        boolean waiting = false;
        for (int s;;) {
            if (((s = lockState) & ~WAITER) == 0) {
                if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, LOCKSTATE, s, WRITER)) {
                    if (waiting)
                        waiter = null;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if ((s & WAITER) == 0) {
                if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, LOCKSTATE, s, s | WAITER)) {
                    waiting = true;
                    waiter = Thread.currentThread();
                }
            }
            else if (waiting)
                LockSupport.park(this);
        }
    }
```

Thread1:CAS the lockstate to WRITER

Thread2:CAS the lockstate to (WRITER|WAITER)

Thread2:LockSupport.park(this)

Thread1:unlockRoot

```
private final void unlockRoot() {
        lockState = 0;
    }
```

then who can unpark the Thread2?

the finally part of find() method need to be done in strict conditions

```
finally {
                        Thread w;
                        if (U.getAndAddInt(this, LOCKSTATE, -READER) ==
                            (READER|WAITER) && (w = waiter) != null)
                            LockSupport.unpark(w);
                    }
```

can somebody tell me if I was thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is based on the assumption that 2 writer-threads could potentially enter the `contendedLock()` method and the second writer would be parked indefinitely by itself which is, of course, impossible as the `putVal`
is [synchronized on the root node](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1031) of the tree in question.

In fact, the `lockState` is only used to orchestrate readers vs writers through CAS and only if both reader and writer try to access the same RB-tree (i.e. they both operate on a key with identical hash).

In that case the writer-thread would park itself once it found `lockState=READER` (and then added the `WAITER` bit to the `lockState` through OR (`s | WAITER`). This value (00000110) will later be used in the `finally` block by the reader to unpark the writer-thread (once it clears the reading state by adding `-READER`, that is -4, and sees the previous value was also 00000110)